# SSAS 2012 DAX SamePeriodLastYear() with Date Dimension

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dax

I have a date dimension and a fact table.  I have two measures:

```
WorkOrdersCount:=
  count(
    FactWorkOrderLifeCycle[Clientsid]
  )
```

and

```
WorkOrdersLastYearCount:=
  CALCULATE(
    count(FactWorkOrderLifeCycle[Clientsid]),
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DimDate[FullDate])
  )
```

WorkOrdersCount is simple and works fine.  I thought WorkOrdersLastYearCount would be simple as well, but I now realize I don't understand SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR().

My date dimension has a DateSID column containing an integer representation of date as YYYYMMDD.  It has two recordkeeping rows with SIDs of -1 and -2 for unknown and TBD dates.  I'm only using the -1 row in this solution.  The data is stored in a SQL Server table and the FullDate column is a "date" type.  The actual value is 1900-01-01.

My fact, FactWorkOrderLifecycle, has a field called InvoicedDateSID that can have a null value which I replace with -1.

No errors are thrown in Visual Studio or when processing the olap, but upon referencing the column in a pivot table I get the following error:

> ERROR - CALCULATION ABORTED: Calculation error in measure
>   'FactWorkOrderLifeCycle'[WorkOrdersLastYearCount]: An invalid numeric
>   representation of a date value was encountered.

Things I've tried (not all make sense):

1. changed SID values to positive integers
2. changed date value in dimdate to 9999-12-31 instead of 1900-01-01 when I saw that DAX dates might start at 1900-03-01
3. adding other dimensions to the pivot first to see if the formula calculates correctly at all.

I'm a DAX noob and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you have some other values in your FullDate column like "1", "2", "TBD", or "Unknown". The SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR is trying to resolve values that match the DATE type. It sounds like you have a value in your DimDate table is not in a format it can resolve.

Comment: so, I changed the dates to use 2050-12-31 instead of 9999-12-31 or 1900-01-01 and things started working when I use the Analyze in Excel option.   This is running on our dev server and, again, it's working.  But when I deploy to dev I still get the same error.  I think for different reasons now though so I'll probably open another question.

Comment: Yes I think 9999-12-31 and 1900-01-01 are out of range

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you calendar table is indeed using a Date data type.
Remove any time component of your dates.
Make sure there are no gaps and no duplicates in your Calendar table.
Make sure you are using fields from your Calendar table on the pivot, and NOT date related fields from your data table.